# Getting/setting an argument's default value dynamically

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Start with the following scenario:

```
class Foo
  def bar(baz={})
    p baz
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
p meth = foo.method(:bar) # => #<Method: Foo#bar>
p meth.parameters # => [[:opt, :baz]]
```

So I can figure out that the method `bar` is optional, but how do I find the default value (`{}`) for the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
foo.bar
```

Since you are not passing in a value for baz, it will print out the default value.

Although, I'm betting you want something that would apply to any method.  The only consistent way I know of, is to look at the source code.

**The Answer:**  Somebody wrote a script that does it [here](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/method+arguments+via+introspection).

However, looking over the script to try and understand just how it pulls out the default values makes my head hurt.

Comment: Wowza.. I figured it would be way easier to get the default values in Ruby. Thanks though, I'll read through the crazyness and try to figure it out =)