# How to retrieve default argument values for a given method definition in JRuby

Tags: methods, parameters, arguments, jruby, default

How can I retrieve the full argument definition for a given method, including default values?

I'm really surprised this isn't in the standard library; but perhaps there is a way?

I've checked out a merb library called 'get_args' but this seems to be old and fail tests.
An promising method is the parameters method as used in the example below but ( as shown in the output below ) this doesn't supply information about defaults.

Example:

```
require 'pp'

class Siren

  def woo(song_style = "tantalising", *other_sailors, target_sailor)
    puts "wooing #{target_sailor} with the #{song_style} song, whilst winking at: #{other_sailors.size} others."
  end

end

sally = Siren.new
sally.woo("John")
puts
pp Siren.instance_method(:woo).parameters
```

Output:

```
wooing John with the tantalising song, whilst winking at: 0 others.

[[:opt, :song_style], [:rest, :other_sailors], [:req, :target_sailor]]
```

But I'd like the 'song_style' to tell me that the default is 'tantalising'.

Anyone know the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting/setting an argument's default value dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873147/getting-setting-an-arguments-default-value-dynamically)

Comment: It is in fact a duplicate, but having enthusiastically checked out the answer supplied on that thread: I found to my horror that it is no longer active! I don't have sufficient points yet to alert that thread of the problem.  :(

Comment: Here is a snapshot of that page: http://web.archive.org/web/20100928212540/http://eigenclass.org/hiki/method+arguments+via+introspection – beware, it's a rather hairy solution! ;)

Answer (score 0):

this is not 100% possible thus not supported in Ruby's API ... 
e.g. what if the method looked like (depending on instance or imagine it calling some "external" method on another object) :

```
def woo(song_style = muu)
  # ...
end
```

in that case it's simply impossible to return a correct default value by introspection